# Why does a function with `readFile` inside Jenkins Pipeline returns wrong type?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Why does a function with `readFile` inside Jenkins Pipeline returns wrong type?

```
@NonCPS
def getChanged(changeTrackingOutput, ruleName, ciTags) {
  echo """CI Tags: ${ciTags}"""

  if (ciTags.contains('build-all')) {
    return true
  }
  // Check output of the change detection.
  def ys = new Yaml()
  def fileData = readFile(changeTrackingOutput)
  echo """File: ${fileData.getClass()}, ${fileData}"""

  def res = ys.load(fileData)
  echo """RRes: ${res.getClass()}, ${res}"""

  def changed = res['changed'].contains(ruleName)
  echo """Type: ${changed.getClass()}, ${changed}"""

  ys = null  // Null everything: https://blog.thesparktree.com/you-dont-know-jenkins-part-3
  res = null
  fileData = null

  return
```

When I use this function inside a `script` step.
I cannot see any output after `readFile(`. Something is really fishy, it appears to me that the function `getChanged` returns somehow after `readFile`. Also outside the type I get is `String` and not `boolean` which it should be.

Its really hard to see whats going on here. Also in OpenBlueOcean I see:

[image]

with nothing after that.

Comment: Does the file `.changes.yaml` exist?  (with the leading `.`?)

Comment: There was a CPS mismatch error I did not see, and the function returned... somehow strange...